# Assigning same name for radio, checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nested-loops

I have created a nested ul li tree. I want a radio or a checkbox control before each li node. For that I have a `class="single/multiple"` for each li. Now I have created a jquery nested function which scans through all the li's and append a radio or a checkbox control. It is working fine.

**JQUERY:**

```
var count = 0;
$(function(){
    AddCBRadNodes($("#tree").children("ul"));
});


function AddCBRadNodes(node) {
    count = count+1;
    $(node).children("li").each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("single")) {
            $(this).prepend("<span><input type='radio' name='rad_"+count+"' /></span>");
        }
        else if($(this).hasClass("multiple")) {
            $(this).prepend("<span><input type='checkbox' name='cb_"+count+"' /></span>");
        }

        //Nesting here
        if($(this).children("ul").children("li").size() > 0) {
            AddCBRadNodes($(this).children("ul"));
        }
    });
}​
```

Fiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/Y46Dw/1/

What I am unable to do is that I need a unique name for each li level. For eg. A1, A2, A3 should have same name but different name than other li's. If you will analyse the controls in firebug then you will understand that my current jquery is assigning `rad_1` to `P1`, `rad_6` to `P2` and `P3`. It is logic issue regarding which I desperately need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified jquery to show only radio.

Here is the working fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/Y46Dw/14/

If there is a previous li sibling then I copied the name or else I have incremented the count.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `count` variable up out of the scope of the recursive function

And increment `count` before the recursive call

http://jsfiddle.net/Y46Dw/10/

**EDIT...**

To keep the same name on the same level -

What if you take `count` and pass it as a parameter to the function?

Like this....

http://jsfiddle.net/Y46Dw/13/

Comment: I need same name for children on the same level. In your fiddle there are 12 unique names.

Comment: you almost there. But there is one more thing and that is all child should have unique name.

Comment: I just realized that  ha.  What if you track iteration of recursion and append that?    I'll jsfiddle it in a sec.

Comment: Anyways, I got the solution. I checked if there is a previous sibling then copy the name or else increment the count. I have posted my fiddle as answer, you can check that.

Answer (score 0):

Always pay attention to what and when you are doing.
Move

```
var count = 0;
```

to the 1st line of your code
and

```
count = count+1;
```

inside

```
 $(node).children("li").each(function() {
```

You need to set the initial value BEFORE you do anything else and increment it EVERY time you do something with it.

Comment: I did exactly as you said. But it is not working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/Y46Dw/8/). Can you please point out what is wrong. Will be best for me if you save the fiddle and give me the link.